# $(form).ajaxSubmit is not a function

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm trying to use the jquery validate plugin to validate a form and submit the contents with an ajax request.

This code is in the head of my document.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact-form').validate({submitHandler: function(form) {
         $(form).ajaxSubmit();   
         contactSuccess() ;
         }
    });
});
```

The validation works.
However, the submission is made normally: On submission, the page reloads.
Of course, I've got a non-js fallback behaviour for browsers that don't have js enabled. But I'd like to get the smoother user experience working.

The error that I see in firebug is:
$(form).ajaxSubmit is not a function

What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: did you include the jquery form plugin? (http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started)

Comment: Are you sure you're loading the library correctly?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I'm guessing you don't have a jquery form plugin included.  `ajaxSubmit` isn't a core jquery function, I believe.

Something like this : http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

**UPD**

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

**UPD - moved to github.io**

```
<script src="https://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

Comment: Dead right! Thanks for the quick answer... I'd just forgotten to include the form plugin the the head of the HTML document. Doh!

Comment: Duuuh, so many scripts to keep track of! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I had a similar problem but in my case, I upgraded jQuery from 1.3.1 to 3.2.1, but I still had jQuery Form Plugin 2.19, which uses deprecated code that is not compatible with jQuery 3.2.1. The solution in my case was to upgrade to jQuery Form Plugin 3.51.0, which is compatible with jQuery 3.2.1.

Answer (score 6):

this is new function so you have to add other lib file after jQuery lib

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

it will work.. I have tested.. hope it will work for you..

Answer (score 3):

Ajax Submit form with out page refresh by using jquery ajax method first include library jquery.js and jquery-form.js then create form in html:

```
<form action="postpage.php" method="POST" id="postForm" >

<div id="flash_success"></div>

name:
<input type="text" name="name" />
password:
<input type="password" name="pass" />
Email:
<input type="text" name="email" />

<input type="submit" name="btn" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
  var options = { 
        target:        '#flash_success',  // your response show in this ID
        beforeSubmit:  callValidationFunction,
        success:       YourResponseFunction  
    };
    // bind to the form's submit event
        jQuery('#postForm').submit(function() { 
            jQuery(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
            return false; 
        }); 


});
function callValidationFunction()
{
 //  validation code for your form HERE
}

function YourResponseFunction(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)
{
    if(responseText=='success')
    {
        $('#flash_success').html('Your Success Message Here!!!');
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 800);

    }else
    {
        $('#flash_success').html('Error Msg Here');

    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact-form').validate({submitHandler: function(form) {
         var data = $('#contact-form').serialize();   
         $.post(
              'url_request',
               {data: data},
               function(response){
                  console.log(response);
               }
          );
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your post please include how/why your post will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ajaxsubmit](http://github.com/bogdan/ajaxsubmit) library.
It does ajax submition as well as validation via ajax.

Also configuration is very flexible to support any kind of UI.

[Live demo available](http://ajaxsubmit.heroku.com) with js, css and html examples.

Comment: link to demo is broken

Answer (score 1):

**Drupal 8**

Drupal 8 does not include JS-libraries to pages automaticly. So most probably if you meet this error you need to attach 'core/jquery.form' library to your page (or form). Add something like this to your render array:

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/jquery.form';
```

Answer (score 1):

Previous link return Http 404: **Use https protocol** :

```
<script src="https://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

Documentation :
https://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Answer (score -4):

```
$(form).ajaxSubmit();
```

triggers another validation resulting to a recursion. try changing it to

```
form.ajaxSubmit();
```

Comment: What? Not even close to true... Why would that trigger any kind of recursion?!