# Submit form through ajax

Tags: html, ajax

My code is working on my localhost. But it not working on Server.

```
        $("#MyUploadForm").ajaxSubmit(options);
```

Please help me.

Comment: what options you have?

Comment: you need to be much more speicifc; what error messages are you getting (via javascript console), show more of your code, etc.

Comment: var options = { 
   target:   '#output',   
   beforeSubmit:  beforeSubmit,   
   uploadProgress: OnProgress,
   success:       afterSuccess,  
   resetForm: false         
  };

Comment: I am getting a TypeError: $(...).ajaxSubmit is not a function error

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265914/form-ajaxsubmit-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have not included the plugin, please add these lines to your html

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

[**http://jquery.malsup.com/form/**](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)

Comment: The OP mentioned nowhere that a plugin is used. AJAX can be done natively with jQuery.

Comment: @dwhite.me ajaxSubmit is function from that plugin. I thought he is referring to that plugin.