# jQuery validation plugin disabling button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to disable my submit button on my form, but it seems what I am doing is not working. The jQuery validation plugin is working on my form and it is validating correctly, but when it comes to submitting the form...the submit button does not disable when I call it to. It's also worth noting that the ajax function is working and data is being transferred to my database table.

**Here's my code**

**HTML**

```
<form class='sign_up' action='' method='POST'>                
            <input id='email' type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            <input id='username' type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            <input id='registerBtn' name='registerBtn' type="submit" value="Create Account">
        </form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".sign_up").validate({
        errorElement: 'div',
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 60,
                email: true,
                remote: {
                    url: 'usernameChecker.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        email: function(){
                            return $("#email").val();
                        },
                    },
                },
            },

            username: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 15,
                alphanumeric: true,
                remote: {
                    url: 'usernameChecker.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        username: function(){
                            return $("#username").val();
                        },
                    },
                },
            },

            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 7,
            }

        },

        messages: {
            email: {
                required: "*Please enter your email.",
                maxlength: "*Emails should not exceed 60 characters.",
                email: "*This is not a valid email.",
                remote: "*That email is already taken."
            },

            username: {
                required: "*Please enter a username.",
                maxlength: "*Username should not exceed 15 characters.",
                alphanumeric: "*Usernames should contain only letters, numbers or underscores.",
                remote: "*That username is already taken."
            },

            password: {
                required: "*Please enter a password.",
                minlength: "*Your password should be at least 7 characters long.",
            }
        },

          submitHandler: function(form) {
          $("#registerBtn").prop("disabled", "disabled");
            $(form).ajaxSubmit();
          }
    });
```

Comment: The button is disabling itself perfectly fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/o7tvcvt6/  ~ although you should probably use `.prop('disabled', true)` instead.

Comment: @Sparky It works fine when you comment out `$(form).ajaxSubmit();` but with that line of code, it does not work. After you hit submit, the console gives an error saying it does not recognize the function `$(form).ajaxSubmit();` but the data is still inserted into the database. If I remove the `.prop` line, then the console recognizes the function

Comment: The data is still inserted because your `form` must be submitting via its `action` attribute, the only explanation if your ajax function is broken.  So basically the original problem of the jQuery not applying the `disabled` property is only a problem because of a JavaScript error.  Ok, back to your comment... [you realize `.ajaxSubmit()` depends on another plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5265914/594235), right?